# Get data JSON Android error

Tags: java, android, json

Did you read this JSON, I'm still new to JSON not managing to get the data.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "cliente": [
        {
            "cpf": "82334673382",
            "endereco": "ewkiewowieou",
            "id": "11",
            "nome": "Wagner Assis"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "82334889929",
            "endereco": "uuqwuwqu",
            "id": "14",
            "nome": "GS Advogados"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "3237287383",
            "endereco": "ewiueiwu",
            "id": "15",
            "nome": "Empreiteira GH"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "73448723349",
            "endereco": "dsgdsjhdjh",
            "id": "17",
            "nome": "CobranÃ§a HH"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "7337474847",
            "endereco": "weuwuewiu",
            "id": "18",
            "nome": "Pollo GH"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "23423423",
            "endereco": "rewrwer",
            "id": "19",
            "nome": "FinanÃ§as LH"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "847384378",
            "endereco": "jsjsdhjsdh",
            "id": "20",
            "nome": "Empreisa SA"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "123456",
            "endereco": "ewewew",
            "id": "21",
            "nome": "JoÃ£o Pedro"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "73447832828",
            "endereco": "dsjdhsjh",
            "id": "22",
            "nome": "Pedro Otavio"
        },
        {
            "cpf": "312312",
            "endereco": "rwwree",
            "id": "23",
            "nome": "Carlos Philip"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the method where I pull the data:

```
public void handleResponse(String response) {

    EditText edFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testeNome);
    EditText edLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testeEnder);
    EditText edEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testeCpf);

    edFirstName.setText("");
    edLastName.setText("");
    edEmail.setText("");

    try {

        //------------------------------//
        //Array Json
        JSONArray JArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
        JSONObject JObjeto = JArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject posicao = JObjeto.getJSONObject(KEY_CLI); 

        String firstName = posicao.getString("id");


        edFirstName.setText(firstName);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

Error saying it is not possible to convert object array. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your `response` string holds an object from what you're showing us which means you can not create a `JSONArray` from it. You should create an object from the `response`, get the array indexed by the key `cliente` and then process each entry in this list.

Comment: so I must deal with my json object and not an array? would show me an example? is that I am new to json and only managed to do with only a customer and not a number ..

Comment: Take a look at the answer below which would be a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a JSONObject initially through `cliente`. The rest of the data comes as `JSONArray`. Parse your object and get a handle of the Array. Iterate over the Array and get the individual elements:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object parsed = parser.parse(response.toString());
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parsed;

JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cliente");

for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
    if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
        JSONObject cpf = (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println(cpf.get("cpf").toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, then I will have to create this parser class json, has any site to show how to assemble the correct structure of json for android?

Comment: @zullyB These are the json classes in use above: `import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;`